# Every time my website loads I want it to first clear the local cache. How in HTML?

Tags: cache-control

I have my two name logos coming in from the right using marquee and stopping exactly where I want (within the  and ).  When pressing Ctrl + F5 it works perfectly.  When pressing F5 only, the images scroll off the  to the left.  I know Ctrl + F5 clears the local cache, and F5 does not.  How can I clear the cache every time the page is loaded or reloaded?  Go to https://beiswenger.com/beiswengerassociates and try it for yourself. I need to resolve what should be a simple problem quickly.

I have tried:



With no luck.  I have even tried sending the page to a default asp and then back.  JBeiswenger

Comment: I don't know if you know that your site is horribly antiquated and uses a multitude of obsolete elements as well as missing required elements.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.